# Using "extern" keyword without #include "file.h"

Tags: c++, include, extern

Right now i read Stephen Prata's book about C++, and learning about extern keyword and its usage. So i have a question. Can i type "extern int var a;" without including a file that defines and initializes this 'a' variable?

```c
#include <iostream>
//#include "vars.h" Not including the file with 'a' variable

using namespace std;

extern int a;

int main()
{   
    cout << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You **do not** need to *include* (`#include`) any file that defines and initializes the `a` variable.  You **do** need to *compile* and *link* the file (and that file's intermediate object file) that defines and initializes the `a` variable.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, provided it is defined _somewhere_.

Comment: Oh, i see! Sorry for asking that mere question. Thank you very much!

Comment: For the sake of compilation of the current file you need nothing more when using `extern int a;`. However for the sake of linking you need to define such a variable `int a` in another *.cpp* file then (possibly in some header included to one).

Comment: I understood. Thank you guys!

Comment: Think of `extern` as a promise to the compiler that the identifier will be defined. Just not here and not now. Side note. Don't do stuff like `extern int a = 0;` I'm not sure if the behavior is defined by the Standard, but in the wild when I've seen this done the initialization cancels out the `extern` and leaves you with a definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `extern` keyword will denote that the variable has external linkage.

> When a name has external linkage, the entity it denotes can be
> referred to by names from scopes of other translation units or from
> other scopes of the same translation unit.

From https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link

If you attempt to run the above code as is, you will get a linker error as `a` is not defined in the current scope. So it will have to get it from another translation unit, which can be done during the linking process.

Comment: Since the question is about c++, it might be noteworthy, that `extern "C" { }` can be also used to control c-style mangled symbol generation, when linking external objects, which were generated with the C compiler..